# Getting any rows which were added before a certain date

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

Would this be possible? I've used this to insert the date into a field called "date":

```
$date=date("m/d/y");
$sql="INSERT INTO pool (date) VALUES('$date' )";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I've used this statement to get the date a week ago:

```
$variable = date('d-m-y', strtotime('-1 week'));
```

So how would I SELECT any rows which were added last week?

Comment: Are you sure date is inserted in DB?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of storing your dates as `m/d/y`, you should store them as Y-m-d :

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
$sql="INSERT INTO pool (date) VALUES('$date' )";
```

In the database, you dates will then look like `2011-04-09`.

That format is much easier to work with : alphabetical comparisons will work.

Which means that searching for rows that are older than a certain date would become something like this :

```
$variable = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
$query = "select * from pool where date < '$variable'";
```

Also note that instead of working with a `date` field which is a varchar (or an equivalent) in your database, you could use a [**`DATE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) column -- which would allow to to work with [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in MySQL.

Comment: Hi! I've changed the column to DATE and made sure all the fields are within a week ago. Although I can't get it to work. I get "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource". Any idea why this is? :(

Comment: You must have an error in your SQL query. use http://fr.php.net/mysql_error to have the error message.

Comment: Glad to hear you found out what the problem was :-) You're welcome ; have fun !

Answer (score 1):

If the date field is a proper date type you can do < or > in your sql query. For example -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > '$date'
```

If you want everything from 1 week ago to now you can do something like the above or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '$date' AND NOW()
```